# How can I hand over data from an Angular2 app to an ASP.NET page?

Tags: asp.net, angular, authentication

I have an existing ASP.NET website with a login. The login procedure is not trivial, because of routing to different front ends on different servers based on which user logs in. There is also some communication/login going on to a classic ASP website.

Now I want to start to decouple the first step of the login procedure using a tiny Angular2 app. Basically this should just collect the user and password and leave the login validation etc. to the existing ASP.NET logic. So from my naive point of view, this is the same as filling out user and password on my existing ASP.NET page and clicking the submit button.

I know that I can make http requests using angular2 and have successfully done so calling SOAP based web services which are part of the login validation process.

I have the idea that I can somehow fake the http request which is executed when submitting the login form in the existing ASP.NET page. But as far as I understand it right now, even if I could make an http request to my login.aspx site the response I would get would sit in my Angular2 obervable as text whereas I would like to leave my Angular2 app and "simply use" that response.

I am not even sure what questions to ask ... but how do I do that?
What have I not considered?

Some options I have:

- It would be possible to change parts of the existing ASP.NET page(s).
- I think it would be OK to open a new browser tab in which the existing ASP.NET app would be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

We need to use static method's to make Ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand the whole picture, but I know that you can load an ASP.NET partial view from an Angular2, or even make an http call to an ASP.NET Controller to get your data.

So I don't really understand your problem there, since the question is not clear, but you could make an http call to an ASP.NET Controller that would manage calls to your different WebServices.

Some clarifications would be helpful for a more detailled answer.